# pic24fj128ga310 uart not working in application, but works with PuTTY

Tags: pic, uart, microchip, rs232

I'm trying to connect a PIC24FJ128GA310 mounted on an Explorer 16 board with an embedded wireless module. I have been able to set up both to communicate perfectly well with PuTTY (an equivalent to Hyperterminal), but they won't communicate with each other!

I haven't configured UART for a microcontroller before, but here is my set-up code (which works for PuTTY):

```
   RPOR8bits.RP17R = 5; // RP5 as U2TX mapped for peripheral pin select 
   RPINR19bits.U2RXR = 10; // RP10 as U2RX mapped for selectable input source
   U2BRG = 25; // 9600 baud rate
   U2MODEbits.UARTEN = 1; // UART2 is enabled
   U2MODEbits.ABAUD = 0; // Auto-baud disabled
   U2MODEbits.RTSMD = 0; // 0 = Flow Control and 1 = Simplex
   U2MODEbits.BRGH = 0; // Low baud rate
   U2STAbits.UTXEN = 1; // Transmit enabled
```

Can anyone help? I have tried both straight-through and null modem cables. The microcontroller is able to show reception of a signal on the U2STAbits.URXDA 'Receive Buffer Data Available bit'.

I can send and receive a string of three character maximum, if flow control and echo settings are the same at both ends, and I terminate the string with '\0'. No hardware is connecting the two except for the RS232 cable and null modem adapter. However I need to reset the microcontroller after each attempt in order for it to show a signal received again. Why do I need to reset it, and why is 3 the maximum number of characters?

When I say it works with PuTTY, I mean that using [this equivalent to Hyperterminal](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html) I am able to send messages to the microcontroller which are displayed on the Explorer 16 LCD display with no problems (if it echoes the characters received back to PuTTY).

*RESOLVED: it was a receive buffer overflow. @Madmanguruman I tried answering but the website won't let me for 8 hours after posting the question, so will do it later...

Comment: Is there any hardware or software handshaking used in putty? You need these to be the same on both ends of the rs232.

Comment: what do you mean by "works with putty"? what kind of tests are you performing?

Comment: @Sidleg Post your resolution as an answer, not as a question edit - otherwise the question could remain open forever. (Answering your own question is OK here)